# How to find WebElement in a List<WebElement> by text?

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver, pattern-matching, vavr

I want to find WebElement in a `List<WebElements>` by text. My method has such arguments: `List<WebElement> webElements, String text`. For matching text I prefer to use [javaslang](http://www.javaslang.io/javaslang-docs/#_pattern_matching) library. So, what we have:

```
protected WebElement findElementByText(List<WebElement> webelements, String text) {

}
```

Using javaslang I wrote such simple matching:

```
Match(webElement.getText()).of(
     Case(text, webElement),
          Case($(), () -> {
               throw nw IllegalArgumentException(webElement.getText() + " does not match " + text);
          })
);
```

I do not understand how in good way to write a loop for finding WebElement in a `List<WebElemnt>` by text. Thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to do it like this:

```
// using javaslang.collection.List
protected WebElement findElementByText(List<WebElement> webElements, String text) {
    return webElements
            .find(webElement -> Objects.equals(webElement.getText(), text))
            .getOrElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No WebElement found containing " + text));
}

// using java.util.List
protected WebElement findElementByText(java.util.List<WebElement> webElements, String text) {
    return webElements
            .stream()
            .filter(webElement -> Objects.equals(webElement.getText(), text))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No WebElement found containing " + text));
}
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Javaslang*

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will write tomorrow what I got )

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need just a simple foreach loop:

```
for(WebElement element : webElements){
    //here is all your matching magic
}
```

Comment: Let's imagine that List<WebElement> has size three and needed element is second. That loop will run just once. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Something does not match ExpectedText message will apear at console.

Comment: as I figured out my first fault was adding IllegalArgumentException. For that reason loop was run just once.

Comment: I have resolved my issue in half. It works with foreach and if else. But maybe somebody could help me to do it using pattern matching.

Comment: @Oleksii don't make the life harder.) Why do you throw exception if you can't handle it? Instead of it return true/false. Then check the answer and if it's true then return your element.